# Synonym for Happy Hour/Cocktails/Hors d'oeuvres

Tags: synonyms

What's a good word that combines happy hour, cocktails and hors d'oeuvres? Inquiring for phasing in a wedding invitation.

> Following the ceremony, join us for ???? at 6pm.

Comment: Consider "refreshments".

Comment: @Lawrence you should post it as an answer. It's perfect.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Thanks for the vote of confidence. Done!

Answer (score 2):

Consider *refreshments*.

> **Refreshments** *noun*
>   1 A light snack or drink: *light refreshments are available*
>   [- ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/refreshment?q=refreshments)